# Cleaning up blurry images using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to take an image of blurry cylindrical objects and get rid of the blur, basically sharpen the image. How do I do that in Matlab?

Comment: Like in the movies where they can take a blurry dark security camera image, infinitely zoom in and magically generate detail that isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

See the "sharpening" section in http://www.aquaphoenix.com/lecture/matlab10/page3.html.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with filters.

See here, section 10.2.4 here: http://www.aquaphoenix.com/lecture/matlab10/page3.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the good answers by others: for the very very simple inputs, you can simply threshold the image if you just need the boundary of those cylinders.